# Magento Paypal Standard Order

Tags: checkout, paypal

So I am using Paypal Standard as my payment method for Mage ver 1.8. For now the method is in Sandbox Mode.

The issue is when I click on place order from Checkout page, it redirects me to Paypal Payment page. Now when I click on ***Cancel and return to Merchant's store***, it redirects me to the store but my cart is empty and the order is placed in admin with the status ***Canceled***.

Is this the default behavior for **Paypal Standard** Payment Method or is there any issue ?

Please Help.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

when you are redirect to PayPal site and click on Cancel and return to Merchant's store ...
your store place order and status is cancel ....

here default behavior of magento .. to create order and set status cancel...

here little error is when you are redirect for PayPal site to  Merchant's store cart never goes empty..

Comment: Lets say if I cancel and return to store and see my cart empty, I log out and login again after a week and then place an order - What will happen in this case ?

Comment: same ... as like before ..... if you are payment successfully paid at that time your order place with processing status... no change with your login and log out and its time

Comment: This will result in ghost orders in backend..What is the solution ?

Comment: to delete ghost order .. install delete order module.. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/delete-orders-5.html or http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/delete-orders-6.html

Comment: Not a solution..

Comment: you can customize your checkout page and get payment first and then go to place order(this is not good solution ) .... this ghost order create is magento functionality we can't change it. it is for security purpose..